# Magento 2 Website Response Time Incredibly High

Tags: php, magento2, digital-ocean

I had a new magento 2 based website developed with a purchased theme hosted on digital ocean. The website ran well for a month. Suddenly, after a day of a google Pmax campaign, the website response time is incredibly high. The homepage loads in 2 mins. Any click event takes 2 mins.

The dev team has done the following :

Theme uninstall
Plugins disabled
Server upgrade & restart
Magento cache & cron
Uploaded a plain HTML
Checked for the code errors
Plugins enabled one by one

We are clueless. I really need it to get going. Any leads on what could be going wrong?

Comment: Quick Update. There seems to be an issue with the meganto theme : Fastest(irony at its best). The website loads super fast with the default theme luma. With Fastest, it just does not respond for 2 minutes.

Comment: You may enable profiler and check which section is taking more time. Also check in server logs if your site is facing automated scanning by various bots.

Comment: Here's the profiling summary :

"Fallback to JQueryUI Compat activated. Your store is missing a dependency for a jQueryUI widget. Identifying and addressing the dependency will drastically improve the performance of your site"

The absurd thing is that this has been a known issue since 2019. My question is how magento or the theme devs leave amateur coders high and dry.

Magento is basically loading all jQuery UI modules because it can't identify which one(s) the custom code needs.

Any thoughts of an easier fix? A theme update does nothing. Really.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be issue with your Magento Theme and cache configuration

What you can do steps to reproduce:

- Check Logs
- Disable third party extensions one by one
- Turn on profiler to check request
- Check cache configuration if its varnish or redis

Have a look into the following tips:
https://www.cloudways.com/blog/magento-optimization/